# degree of differential equation $\sqrt{1+\frac{dy}{dx}}+\frac{dy}{dx}=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Finding degree of the following differential equation
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{dy}{dx}}+\frac{dy}{dx}=x$$
I know a similar question like this has been asked but this one is different .
So to calculate the degree of this differential equation(DE) we bring this DE in polynomial form .
We write this as $$\sqrt{1+\frac{dy}{dx}}=x-\frac{dy}{dx}$$ and then we square both the sides to get the degree as 2.

But what if we do the manupulations in the following way?
Directly square the origional one and rearrange to get,
$$1+\frac{dy}{dx}+{(\frac{dy}{dx})}^2-x^2=-2\sqrt{1+\frac{dy}{dx}}$$
Square this equation once again and obtain the equation in polynomial form of the derivatives , And now this tells that the degree of this equation is 4 .
So why is this the wrong way ?Is there any restriction to the manupulations we have to do to make the given DE in polynomial form of derivatives ?

Comment: I never did get an answer in one of your other threads about why the degree matters.

Comment: @Ian Which thread ? This is my first question on differential equation

Comment: My bad, that was a different OP.

Answer (score 1):

This differential equation does not have a degree, not even in its leading derivative.

What you compute is a related differential equation that has also other solutions than the original one, so it is not equivalent. As that is now a polynomial in all variables, you can assign a degree.

One can also write this transformation as multiplication with a factor according to a binary formula
$$
0=\left(\sqrt{1+y'}+(y'-x)\right)\left(\sqrt{1+y'}-(y'-x)\right)
=1+y'-(y'-x)^2
$$
Nothing prevents you from adding further polynomial factors, increasing the degree and the set of spurious solutions. But that gets you further and further away from the original equation.

Comment: So if we were to solve the original DE , can we solve it without converting into polynomial form? And even if we square (i.e make the minimum possible manupulations ) will it give some extra solutions too ?

Comment: This is quite another question. The quadratic equation has 0, 1 or 2 solutions $y'$. The given equation adds to that the condition $y'\ge -1$. Next you have the condition that $y'$ has to be continuous, which in most cases restricts locally the value of $y'$. The quadratic polynomial is the minimal polynomial for this equation, all other polynomials contain it as factor. Thus if you have to determine a degree, and "none" is not an admissible answer, then the degree is $2$.

Comment: Also note that $p\mapsto p+\sqrt{1+p}$ is monotonically increasing for $p>-1$, so that the equation always has a unique solution if it has a solution at all, that is, for $x>-1$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to put $y'=p$ and find parametric equations for $x,y$:

$$x=p+\sqrt{1+p}$$

$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{p}=\frac{dp}{dy}+\frac{\frac{dp}{dy}}{2\sqrt{1+p}}$

with $dy/dp=\dot{y}, dx/dp=\dot{x}$ we have

$$\dot{y}=p\left(1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+p}}\right)$$

$$y=\int\left(p+\frac{p}{2\sqrt{1+p}}\right)dp+C$$